# Higher quality of JPEG frames extracted with FFMPEG from MP4 video

Tags: video, ffmpeg, compression, jpeg

I got a 4k mp4 video file and my goal is to extract the individual frames. Unfortunately, the video is quite big ~10GB and storing all the frames lossless (e.g. using png, results in 12MB per frame) is not an option. Therefore, I tired to save directly JPEG images. For me quality is more important than a small file size around 1MB would be good.
To do so I used FFMPEG as follows:

`ffmpeg -ss 00:04:52 -i video.MP4 -qscale:v $quality -frames:v 1 output-$quality.jpg`

I tried the full range from 2 to 31 for $quality and obtained the blue curve in the plot (PSNR vs. File size)

Additionally, I extracted the frame and saved it as PNG and used convert from ImageMagick to compress the PNG file as follows:

`convert -quality $quality% frame.png output-$quality.jpg`

Again I tried the full range for $quality from 10 to 100 and obtained the orange line in the plot (The highest quality is 50dB but uses 6MB, so I only show the results up to 2MB).

Now, my questions are as follows. Why is the quality of ffmpeg that much worse than when using ImageMagick? Is it possible to increase the quality of the JPEG frames using ffmpeg directly or do I need to go via the PNG and then to JPEG. The later method is somehow suboptimal because it requires storing the png and will be much slower. Any suggestions? My guess is that ffmpeg trades quality vs. speed...

PSNR vs. File Size plot
[image: PSNR vs. File Size plot]

Comment: Try `ffmpeg -ss 00:04:52 -i video.MP4 -qscale:v 1 -qmin 1 -qmax 1 -frames:v 1 output.jpg`